# angular-ui/bootstrap ratting issue on collection-repeat ionic

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework, angular-ui-bootstrap

I am using [**angular-ui/bootstrap**](http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/) the component Rating (ui.bootstrap.rating).

My issue that max property isn't working correctly when I am using **collection-repeat**.

Its shows me always only one icon max, Also when I trying to play with pro of collection-repeat  then search some time showing less icons, but If I an using **ng-repat** all works great.
this my code:

```
<li class="item"  collection-repeat=" contact in contacts |filter: data.searchText">
      <!--<li class="item" ng-repeat=" contact in contacts |filter: data.searchText">-->
  <div class="row  larger font">

  <div  class ="col" ng-init="contact.active">
        <uib-rating ng-model="contact.active" max={{contact.total}} 
         state-on="'ion-person-stalker positive '" state-off="'ion-person-stalker'" 
         ng-click="changeActive(contact);data.searchText =''"></uib-rating> </div>
```

the basic link for code of it [plnkr](http://codepen.io/vitaly87/pen/MeweJB?editors=0001) this is without collection repeat

UPDATE:
link with example updated.

Comment: Make a fiddle or at least describe what libs are u using

Comment: Hard to help when demo doesn't reproduce issue. You never even saved the plunker and link goes to a blank

Comment: I edit the link but the issue its pure without ionic. when I am doing collection-repeat then its going all wrong...

Comment: @charlietfl I updated the link with example

Comment: No idea what to do or look for in demo. What does *"going all wrong"* mean?

Comment: the icons should fit the total. and the color should be colored by active attribute

Comment: any other derctive that is working with collection and can be set 0 rating ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because collection-repeater renders into the DOM only as many items as are currently visible. So it does not render immediately. That's why you don't have access to the contact variable in uib-rating when it started rendering. If your contacts list isn't very big than you can use ng-repeat without any problems and losing performance.

Comment: The issue that my list is big

Comment: Unfortunately, there's no other way: https://github.com/driftyco/ionic/issues/3655